# Error/Access log of visual studio asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm very new to C# and ASP.NET for web development. I am using Visual studio. 
I built a small web application with one html page that sends a request (using angularJS) to a function in my ApiController. It returns with error 500. (I see it in inspect elements of my browser).

I want to know more information about the error but I can't see anything in the output panel of visual studio.

I have some experience in Django+Python in PyCharm and I expect to see something like PyCharm terminal showing all the requests hitting server, and possible internal errors.

Can someone help with where can I find this kind of info please?
(I know it's a very basic question but that's how beginner I am in visual studio)

Comment: Did you debug the code? Did you check if ApiController code is executing?

Comment: Yes it is executing. I know I can go on with Debug.WriteLine() in debug mode to print out something, but isn't there any other way to see the requests coming and whatever happens to them?

Comment: Then you need to debug the code and check which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Add [`breakpoints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx), [`watch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) variables, etc. during your `debug`ing session. You have so many options _other_ and _better_ than simple logging.

Answer (score 0):

Some options you may have with VS is **Break On All Errors**,Enable Logging with Logging provider.

**Break On All Errors**

In Visual Studio press **Alt+Ctrl+E**.It will show exception settings windows.Tick the common language run time exceptions.When you tick it, it will break the execution when ever exception throws.At development environment i find this most helpful than out put window and logging.

When code breaks have a look at details and the call stack to get bigger idea about what is happening.

[image: Exceptions Settings Window of VS]

**Enable Logging with Logging Provider**

Use some logging provider like NLog and configure logging.But in this case you need to write to the log.Again for production environment you really need those logs.
Further if you are using Asp.Net Core [logging with asp net core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x)  may help you.

In addition to that use a web debugging proxy like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).Something like that becomes very useful when it comes to inspecting requests in apis.

Other than those you can use breakpoints,immediate window,call stack and watch window.

Comment: Thanks! Checking the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" actually helps a lot!